# Popular Jtable com dados do BD sem utilizar o DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gridview

Estou fazendo um projeto todo em camadas e li em algum lugar que o uso do DefaultTableModel não é muito recomendado. Estou tentando receber valores cadastrados no BD e preencher um jTable com esses valores. Abaixo seguem as classes definidas.

Método da Camada DAO para listar Pessoas cadastradas:

```
 public List listarTodas() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

   List lista;
   try (Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnectionFactory()) {
     lista = new ArrayList();
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM Pessoa";
     try (PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
         while (rs.next()) {
             Pessoa p = resultSet2Model(rs);
             lista.add(p);
         }
     }
}
    return lista;
```

}

Acredito que agora deve-se implementar a Camadas Business e View. Não é isso?

Comment: Fircar recriando a mesma duvida nao ajuda muito. Faça o que eu sugeri na outra pergunta, edite e forneça um **[mcve]** para que seu problema possa ser melhor analisado.

Comment: Peço desculpas.

Comment: Adicionei uma nova pergunta nas duplicadas, dê uma lida nela. Ela mostra como criar um model pra tabela.

Comment: Agradeço muito.  Como devo proceder na próxima ? É possível usar uma pergunta de já feita para fazer outra?

Comment: Já leu? Já testou a dica la? Primeiro tente fazer conforme está explicado. Senao vai ser duplicata de novo. Tente ler com calma, fazer um exemplo mais simples, e depois aplicar no seu programa. Se pintar duvida sobre alguma coisa la, ai você pergunta aqui.